# How do I resolve my leak issue?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, amazon-s3, cfnetwork

I have built an application for iOS 8 and after a memory test I found a leak.

The leak is same and repeats after I upload my files to AWS storage.

**Leak massage:**

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
_CFStreamDelegate   1   0x18914f30  32 Bytes    CFNetwork   HTTPNetConnection::transmitRequest(HTTPNetStreamInfo*, __CoreWriteStream*, CFStreamError*, unsigned char)
```

[image: Leak]

[image: leak Tree]
I found a function that couse this leak:

//Amazone upload

```
-(void)uploadAWS{

    NSString *fileName = DB_File;
    NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


    [self.transferManager cancelAll];

    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    uploadRequest.key = UserName;
    uploadRequest.bucket = BUCKET_NAME;
    uploadRequest.contentType = @"application/x-sqlite3";

    unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil] fileSize];
    uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];
    [[self.transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                switch (task.error.code) {
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                    {
                        //LogError(@"AWS Cancelled - Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
                        break;
                    }
                    case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                    {
                        LogError(@"AWS Paused - Upload failed: [%@]",task.error);
                    }
                        break;

                    default:
                        LogError(@"AWS status [%ld]:Upload failed: [%@]",(long)task.error.code,task.error);
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                LogError(@"Upload failed: [%@]", task.error);
            }
        }

        if (task.result) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                LogDebug(@"Upload ok: [%@]", task.error);
            });
        }
        return nil;
    }];

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, someone know the answer?